# Add more routing to asp.net MVC Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one map route like :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );



    }
```

but I want to add more route URL , how can I do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add another `MapRoute()`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

routes.MapRoute(
    "SecondRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{tags}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", tags = "" }
);
```

I suggest you go through [this excellent post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) on routing by The Gu.